# Android progress bar with swipe

Tags: android, progress-bar, swipe

I'd like to create application with many pages and scrolling it by swipe on the top line.
[Something like this](http://s019.radikal.ru/i601/1407/b3/83e116d267de.png).
I think it's a progress bar view, but how I can implement scroll handler?
Maybe there are some ready-made options or libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) from standart Android UI components.